# Unable to install glib library with meson

Tags: makefile, glib, meson-build

I am trying to install latest version glib version 2.64.3 library which uses `meson` build system to compile glib code.

While installing glib i am trying to give custom options to compiler to compile with specific gcc version...etc.

Here is my command :-

```
/test/common/pkgs/python/v3.6.1/bin/meson setup glib_install  -Dbuild.cpp_args="-fPIC" -Dbuild.c_args='-fPIC -O2' -Dc_link_args='/test/common/pkgs/gcc/v6.3.0/lib64' -Ddefault_library=both -Db_staticpic=true -Dprefix='/home/user/test/glib-2.64.3/glib-2.64.3/glib_install'
```

I am getting following issue :-

```
The Meson build system
Version: 0.54.2
Source dir: /home/user/extlibs/glib-2.64.3/glib-2.64.3
Build dir: /home/user/extlibs/glib-2.64.3/glib-2.64.3/glib_install
Build type: native build
WARNING: Unknown options: "c_args, cpp_args"
The value of new options can be set with:
meson setup <builddir> --reconfigure -Dnew_option=new_value ...
Project name: glib
Project version: 2.64.3
meson.build:1:0: ERROR: Compiler cc can not compile programs.
```

I am not sure if i am missing something here. I could not find much info about like how can we provide custom arguments to use specific compiler flags while running meson. Let me know if i am missing something here.

Answer (score 0):

Check in your `glib_install/meson-logs/meson-log.txt` file to see why the configuration is failing, but as a start it seems you need to pass `-Dcpp_args="-fPIC" -Dc_args='-fPIC -O2'` (without `build.`) on the command line.

Comment: ptomato,i am new to meson build system. i want to compile glib source with specific gcc version .How to ask meson to compile with specific gcc version.

Comment: If you open a new question for that, you're more likely to get good help. No one will discover it in this comment under the post.